# Not able to navigate to another UIViewController programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I am trying to navigate to "Home" view controller and for this I have written the following code in the ContainerViewController. But once the code executes, the application hangs and it show 100% CPU usage. Please help.

```
- (IBAction) home:(UIButton *)sender

{

    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];

    //[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Put your code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: here.. Then only Can check what is your problem..

Answer (score 1):

I have a question for you

1-If You want to push SecondViewController on to FirstViewController then your code is good enough

2-If you have a containerview in firstViewController and you want to add SecondViewcontroller's view to firstViewController

then use this code

```
UIViewController*vc1 = [[test1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

//add to the container vc which is self    
[self addChildViewController:vc1];

//the entry view (will be removed from it superview later by the api)
[self.view addSubview:vc1.view];
```

Comment: There are two container view controller on each screen and they act as header and footer. I have just load the Home screen when Home button is clicked. This is basically done from login screen, logout screen.

Comment: I  did not properly understand your question what you wan't achieve using two containerViewController in two different Viewcontroller. I think you can achieve this by using only one containerViewController like in tutorial
  http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/4
or you can use this
https://github.com/defagos/CoconutKit/wiki/Containers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an unwind segue here. In your first view controller add :

```
- (IBAction)unwindToFirstViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
}
```

You then need to hook up each of your view controllers home button to the green Exit button at the bottom of the view controller, choosing the unwindToMainMenu option. This will then take you back to the first view controller when pressed.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and there is no green exit button. Please tell me how can I check as suggested by you. By the way what's wrong with my code? The same code is working when I implement logout functionality. Why the does the application hang here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried popping the current view?

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or just popping to root?

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or setting a new stack?

```
navigationController?.setViewControllers(homeViewController, animated: true)
```

The code is in Swift but it would work the same in ObjectiveC

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does provide a way for the author to navigate to his "Home" view controller

Comment: I will check and let you know. By the way what's wrong with my code? The same code is working when I implement logout functionality. Why the does the application hang here?